# Extending rectangular polygon in one direction until it intersects with another polygon using Shapely

Tags: python, computational-geometry, shapely

Is there a way to extend polygons in Shapely? I have a scenario which looks as follows

[image]

What I would like to do is to extend the horizontal polygon to the vertical one.

The polygons exteriors are represented as follows:

```
vert_poly.exterior.xy
```

```
(array('d', [55.63234329223633, 517.281494140625, 517.281494140625, 55.63234329223633, 55.63234329223633]),
 array('d', [632.2301635742188, 632.2301635742188, 647.7040405273438, 647.7040405273438, 632.2301635742188]))
```

and

```
hor_poly.exterior.xy
```

```
(array('d', [560.3878784179688, 575.0977172851562, 575.0977172851562, 560.3878784179688, 560.3878784179688]),
 array('d', [64.83158111572266, 64.83158111572266, 904.9833984375, 904.9833984375, 64.83158111572266]))
```

Using `vert_poly = vert_poly.buffer(vert_poly.distance(hor_poly))` returns

[image]

which is in right the direction, but not quite. This creates the ellipse-like shape around the rectangle. But what I would like to achieve is to extend the horizontal rectangle so that the two end points of it would connect with the vertical one.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use the

`shapely.affinity.scale(geom, xfact=1.0, yfact=1.0, zfact=1.0, origin='center')`

method. This can scale your horizontal polygon to your vertical.
I would calculate the scaling factor using the `object.bounds` attribute which gives you a set of your outer limits `(minx, miny, maxx, maxy)`. You can do this for both polygons and then calculate the scaling factor as:

```
hminx, hminy, hmaxx, hmaxy = hor_poly.bounds
vminx, hminy, hmaxx, hmaxy = vert_poly.bounds

xfact = (hmaxx-hminx)/(vminx-hmaxx)

hor_poly = scale(hor_poly, xfact=xfact)
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally I would suggest over-enlarging the left polygon, call `intersection()`, and construct the new polygon from the returned points, but your question is so specific that you can work with coordinates.

### General

Say your left rectangle is `(X1,Y1),(X2,Y2)` (top left/bottom right) and your right rectangle is `(X3,Y3),(X4,Y4)`. Then the extended left rectangle is `(X1,Y1),(X2,Y3)`.

### Shapely

```
# let left, right be the given Polygons
extended_left = Polygon( [ left.bounds[:2], (right.bounds[0], left.bounds[1]), \
                          (right.bounds[0], left.bounds[3]), left.bounds[2:]  ] )
```